# TFS with 2 application server in different domains

Tags: tfs

In our current setup (TFS2017), we have 2 separate TFS instances: 1 on domain X which is internal, 1 on domain Y which is in DMZ.

Now, I would like to have a setup which is basically 1 instance, with the database internal (on domain X), but with 2 application tiers, 1 on X and 1 on Y.
Is this scenario possible?

I have my doubts as the apptiers are in different domains. But maybe there are some workarounds so we can make it happen anyway.

Interested to hearing suggestions.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Purpose is to minimize the number of TFS instances and related costs. My idea is to have just 1 server with 2 entry points, from internal and from external.